# Get text from TextInput defined in .kv file from class

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following code in python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
class UI(Widget):
    pass

class UIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()

    def process(self):
        text = self.ids.input.text
        print(text)
```

and in UI.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<UI>:
    title: 'InputDialog'
    auto_dismiss: False
    id: 'test1'

    RelativeLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.pos
        size: root.size
        id: 'test2'

        TextInput:
            id: 'input'
            hint_text:'Enter compounds'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.5
```

now if I call process() I get the error `'UIApp' object has no attribute 'ids'`. Alright. Now I try replacing `self` with `UI`: `AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object has no attribute 'input'`. Trying to adress 'test1' also didn't help, neither did removing the ' around the ids in the .kv file.

Is there a way to get the input from the field without creating this field programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

In your kv file, you have defined `id` as string.

[Kivy » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

> Warning
>
> When assigning a value to id, remember that the value isn’t a string.
>   There are no quotes: good -> id: value, bad -> id: 'value'

## Solution

1. In your kv file, remove single quotes from all the `id`
2. In your Python script, replace `self.ids.input.text` with `self.root.ids.input.text` because the `ids` were defined under the root, `class UI()`

## Example

### kv file

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<UI>:
    title: 'InputDialog'
    auto_dismiss: False
    id: test1

    RelativeLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.pos
        size: root.size
        id: test2

        TextInput:
            id: input
            hint_text:'Enter compounds'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.705}
            size_hint: 0.95, 0.5
            on_text: app.process()
```

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class UI(Widget):
    pass


class UIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()

    def process(self):
        text = self.root.ids.input.text
        print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    UIApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Accesing textinput in kv file using ids]

Comment: As I have stated in my post, "Trying to adress 'test1' also didn't help, neither did removing the ' around the ids in the .kv file."

Comment: Please refer to updated post with Python script, `on_text` event in kv file, and print screen of output from method `process()`.

Comment: `<class '__main__.UI'>
klklkijiojoij`

Works, the Builder seems to work better if placed in `if __name__ == "__main__":`